# kivy_garden.contextmenu: how to prevent its touch events from reaching other widgets?

Tags: events, kivy, contextmenu

Trying to learn Kivy.

I am using the kivy_garden.contextmenu which I open when I right click on a widget.
This works.
But when clicking un element in the context menu, I am receiving the on_touch_xxx events on the underneath widget anyway (here it is myWidget) .

My first thought was I could use flags to avoid this behaviour, e.g. setting a value menu_is_showing to True when I show the menu, and ignoring the underneath's widget's on_touch_up if the menu is showing. I did it and it was almost working (a was never notified the menu had been closed by click outside of it so the flag system would break in that case)...

Then I realised (while writing here) I could create a property for the context menu "visible", which made it all work as I expect a context menu would.
And here is the working code (which you are welcome to comment/correct):

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
import kivy_garden.contextmenu
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

kv = '''
<myWidget>:
    on_touch_up: root._on_touch_up(*args[1:])
    menu_visible: context_menu.visible
    
    BoxLayout:
        id: boxlayout1
        pos_hint : {'x':0, 'y':0}
        size_hint: 1,1
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (0, 0, 1, 1)
            Rectangle:
                #texture: self.texture
                size: self.width-10, self.height-10
                pos: self.x+5, self.y+5

    ContextMenu:
        id: context_menu
        visible: False
        cancel_handler_widget: root  

        ContextMenuTextItem:
            text: "action 1"
            on_release: root._action1(); root._hide_menu() 
        ContextMenuTextItem:
            text: "action 2"
            on_release: root._action2(); root._hide_menu()                     

<myLayout>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Dummy"

        myWidget:
            id: floatlayout1
  
'''

Builder.load_string(kv)

class myWidget(FloatLayout):
    menu_visible = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(myWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def _action1(self):
        print("Do Action 1")

    def _action2(self):
        print("Do Action 2")

    def _on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if self.menu_visible:
            return

        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and touch.button == 'left':
            print("Left Click reached the blue area")
        elif self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and touch.button == 'right':
            print("Right Click reached the blue area")
            self.ids.context_menu.show(*touch.pos)

    def _hide_menu(self):
        self.ids.context_menu.hide()

class myLayout(FloatLayout):
    pass

class testApp(App):
    def build_config(self, config):
        Config.set('kivy', 'exit_on_escape', '0')
        Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')
        self.title = 'Testing Context Menu and Layouts'

    def build(self):
        return myLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testApp().run()
```

Try clicking left and right in the blue area and check the console output. (the left button in the layout is only there to add an offset and make sure things I do in the blue area do not align by chance just because it would be in (0,0))

And that's fine, but I would have thought a context menu would already do that, and by default would not propagate the touch events to other widgets. Is there a way to do that?
If so, could you please be so kind to tell me how you'd do that?

Thanks for your time.
C

Comment: I think you are just seeing normal event propagation. And I don't see what your `menu_visible` construction does for you.

Comment: @JohnAnderson thanks for your answer. If you comment the check "if self.menu_visible:" in _on_touch_up, the click you do on the context menu reaches the myWidget. But it shouldn't, the menu should 'eat' it. Hence this menu_visible.

Comment: Imagine it's a drawing app and the left click draws a circle on myWidget (in on_touch_up), and the right click opens a context menu with a few actions. 
Now say I right click, the menu shows and I click an item on it. Without my menu_visible flag, this last click on the menu item triggers on_touch_up on myWidget, and so a circle will be drawn on it, which is not what I want. Somehow the menu should intercept this event.
What would be the way to do so if not with this menu_visible flag? Thank you.